# Build Taylor series of functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I would like to ask what is the general procedure for calculating such examples.

Build Taylor series of functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$
at the point $a = −1$ and determine all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which it converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a function that is infinitely differentiable at some point $a$ in its domain, then the Taylor series of $f$ at $a$ is the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

This means that you can find the Taylor series of any function  by simply computing the numbers $f^{(n)}(a)$. In your case, you'll want to calculate $f^{(n)}(-1)$ for all integers $n\geq 0$.

The case $n=0$ is understood to be the *value* of $f$ at $-1$, so

\begin{align*}
f^{(0)}(-1) &= f(-1)\\
&= \frac{1}{(-1)^2}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

For all other values of $n$, you'll need to start differentiating.

\begin{align*}
f^{(1)}(-1) &= \left[\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x^2}\right]_{x=-1}\\
&= \left[-\frac{2}{x^3}\right]_{x=-1}\\
&= -\frac{2}{(-1)^3}\\
&= 2 = 2!
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
f^{(2)}(-1) &= \left[\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{1}{x^2}\right]_{x=-1}\\
&= \left[\frac{6}{x^4}\right]_{x=-1}\\
&= \frac{6}{(-1)^4}\\
&= 6 = 3!
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
f^{(3)}(-1) &= \left[\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\frac{1}{x^2}\right]_{x=-1}\\
&= \left[-\frac{24}{x^5}\right]_{x=-1}\\
&= -\frac{24}{(-1)^5}\\
&= 24 = 4!
\end{align*}

Using induction, it's easy to prove that $f^{(n)}(-1)=(n+1)!$ in general, so the Taylor series is

\begin{align*}
& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\left(x-(-1)\right)^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x+1)^n
\end{align*}

To find the radius of convergence of the series (and hence the set of all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where the series converges), you can use the ratio test or the root test. Here, it's better to use the ratio test.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+2)(x+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(x+1)^n}\right| &= \lim_{n\to\infty}|x+1|\cdot\frac{n+2}{n+1}\\
&= |x+1|\cdot 1\\
&= |x+1|
\end{align*}

It follows that the series converges if $|x+1|<1$ ($-2<x<0$), and diverges if $|x+1|>1$ ($x<-2$ or $x>0$), so the radius of convergence is $1$. To determine if the series converges for $x=-2$ or $x=0$, you'll need to test

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(-2+1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (n+1)$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(0+1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)$$

for convergence. Since they both clearly diverge, the series converges for $x\in(-2,0)$.

Whether or not the series actually converges to $f$ is another question. The answer happens to be yes in this case, so for $x\in(-2,0)$, you can finally write

$$\frac{1}{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x+1)^n$$